# WSGI loads settings of the wrong project: how to debug?

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I have two django based web applications on the same server.
One of them i'll call **CORRECT_PROJECT** and the other one **WRONG_PROJECT**

The last one, CORRECT_PROJECT, is installed using a virtual environment and uses a different version of django (1.4). There's a very strange problem: sometimes, usually after a log out or an email confirmation  (but sometimes looks just random!), the server returns a **500 internal server error** and the error log says

> **"Could not import settings 'WRONG_PROJECT.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module name WRONG_PROJECT.settings, refer: CORRECT_PROJECT/URL"**

That is, by loading CORRECT_PROJECT, sometimes the system (WSGI? Apache? Django?) tries to load the settings from WRONG_PROJECT.

By hitting refresh aggressively the error disappears.
What could be wrong? How can I debug?

CORRECT_PROJECT uses WSGI in deamon mode.

### Solution

Use deamon mode: http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using wsgi.py from Django 1.4. That will not work when hosting multiple web apps in the same process.

Best solution is to use daemon mode and delegate each to a distinct daemon process group.

If can't do that, change the wsgi.py files of both so they do not use:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

but instead use:

```
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "mysite.settings"
```

Change mysite.settings as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Graham! I've been searching for a solution to this problem for several days.

Comment: could you add a link to the page in which is explained the right syntax for the distinct daemon process solution?

Comment: in the end I had to switch to the deamon mode, I had to set WSGISocketPrefix too because on redhat.

Comment: Read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html for daemon mode example and why you want to use it.

Comment: Also read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html which explains original issue.